# “Recursive” timeouts in AJAX callbacks fill up memory. How can I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, settimeout

I am working on a dashboard project where multiple widgets (like a dozen) need to be updated via an AJAX source every 5 seconds or so. I am currently using `setTimeout` to queue a widget update, which is called everytime the widget is actually updated (not technically a recursion, but…). This is how the code looks

```
var update;
(update = function() {
  $.get(source, function() {
    // Do something
    setTimeout(update, 5000);
  });
})();
```

After a few hours of the page running (Chromium 21), it can easily OOM my 8GB RAM.
As the client uses IE6 on very small configurations (< 1GB RAM), the issue is even more important.

How could I avoid this quirk?

Comment: IE6? This is a "memory-leak browser", you know that? :) There are probably like thousand resons why it leaks. But one thing that I think is true: it has nothing to do with periodic update itself. It's the `// Do something` stuff which leaks memory.

Comment: IE6 Is about 11 years old. There's your problem.

Comment: Agreeing with @freakish here.  What exactly is the "something"?

Comment: I also experience these leaks on Chromium, this is why I am stunned. The `// Do something` is a just a jqplot diagram creation with updated data. I will look into it!

Comment: @Iso This either means that jqplot leaks memory ( I've never heard of that library ) or you are updating the data incorrectly. Show us your code and we'll have a look.

Comment: @freakish this is a jQuery plugin to create a handfull of charts. [Here is the relevant part of the code](http://paste.awesom.eu/Iso/AF5).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks freakish & Pointy, the leak was indeed caused by jqPlot. Thing is, you have to use the `.destroy()` method on said plot, and then remove (and not empty) its DOM container, before creating another one and redrawing a plot.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval instead. That way you only generate one timer and don't need to start a new one every five seconds, which might consume some sort of handle in the browser.

I actually wouldn't have thought setTimeout to leak, but there is a clearTimeout function. Just for researching purposes you could try saving the returnvalue of setTimeout and clearing it, before starting the next one.

Comment: `setInterval` was not an option here since the AJAX request can potentially take more than 5 seconds to complete and I do not want HTTP requests to queue. Using `setTimeout` ensures that updates are run consecutively, even if they are not exactly 5 seconds apart (which is not a problem in my project).